# Font book: duplicates are not actually duplicates

Tags: font

I have a problem when installing new fonts on Font book.
I'm want to use this font: https://github.com/sunaku/tamzen-font, following the doc I download the zip, extract it and drag & drop all of the content of the `/ttf` folder into the app Font Book.

The problem is that of all the different font sizes available in the `/ttf` folder, when I try to select on of the new font, apps (like iTerm) recognise only one: TamzenForPowerline

[image]

In Font book all the different variants of the font are marked as duplicated, even though they are not (as you can see from the image the fonts are different):

[image]

Now, how can I tell Font book that those font are actually different?

Comment: It may be that the font is not constructed in a way that MacOS likes. Individual files for different sizes is a bit odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is based on bitmap fonts (OTB) which in the past where optimised for a certain font size. This is not a font family. Therefore the Font ID - which is used by Fontbook to identify fonts - of each of them is the same.
You could use e.g. [FontForge](https://fontforge.org/en-US/) to change the ID, but for a variety of reasons I wouldn’t recommend that. Why not use a vectorbased, monospaced font? There are lots available for free including bitmap-like looking  ones e.g. [here](https://fonts.google.com/?category=Monospace), [here](https://www.dafont.com/bittypix-monospace.font) or [here](https://www.fontspace.com/search?q=Bitmap).

Comment: From an examination of the fonts, it's not the Font ID, but the internal font name that is the same for several different fonts.