# Resolve font duplicates

Tags: macos, font

I'm installing this font on my mac: https://github.com/sunaku/tamzen-font

The installation is pretty straightforward: it's enough to go to the app "Font Book", click "Add font" and select the `.ttf` version of the downloaded font.

The problem is that Font Book see all the different variants of the font as the same:
[image]

If I try to resolve the conflict manually, it just makes me choose the version to keep, and it doesn't understand that all those versions are different.

How can I make sure I can import all the different variants of the font?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Font book: duplicates are not actually duplicates](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/419763/font-book-duplicates-are-not-actually-duplicates) It appears you asked this same question a year ago as well...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the fonts have been created incorrectly.

Each font needs to have a unique font name, e.g. Tamzen-14 and Tamzen-15 can't both be "Tamzen".

[image]

All the Medium weights have the same full name of "Tamzen".

If fonts have the same font name -- the internal fontname, not the filename -- then FontBook will treat them as duplicates.

Either they should all be in the **Tamzen** family, but with their Styles indicating each size and weight, e.g. Style: "*14 Bold*" and "*14 Regular*", "*15 Bold*", "*15 Regular*";

or they should be in different font family names, each with *Bold* and *Medium*, e.g. "**Tamzen 14**" *Medium* and *Bold*, and "**Tamzen 15**" *Medium* and *Bold*.

The licence gives you permission to modify the fonts: you will need to use a font editor like FontForge to change the names of each font to something unique.
[*This has been mentioned before.*](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/419819/5472)

You should also file an issue with the developer.